# Cannot find class pe_mcollective

Tags: puppet

I'm migrating to Puppet Enterprise. Already pushed through a few issues, but now faced with this annoying problem during an agent run

```
... Could not find class pe_mcollective ...
```

First off I'm not even using MCollective (at least not yet). Is there any way I can disable the 'need' for it temporarily? I didn't see anything explicitly enabling it in `puppet.conf`.

I ran `locate` and quickly found a file `/opt/puppet/share/puppet/modules/pe_mcollective/manifests/init.pp` which defines `pe_mcollective`. So it seems the code is on the box, but it's not being found during an agent run.

Any idea how I can point puppet 'enterprise' in the right direction?

Comment: Can you tell us how you installed Puppet Enterprise?

Comment: I downloaded the code and ran the installer. More or less following this link - http://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/install_basic.html

Comment: Did you remove the old Puppet packages? Everything in Puppet Enterprise is named "pe-*".

Comment: Hmm, that's a good idea. I thought I removed them all, but I'll double check. Maybe something lower in the stack needs to be replaced yet.

Comment: Double checked, all dependencies look good (reinstalled for good measure). I added `:/opt/puppet/share/puppet/modules` to my module path which seemed to help (lots of additional output during agent run), but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! There were 2 `modulepath` declarations in the new `puppet.conf` file. I put mine in from the old configuration not realizing there was already a `modulepath` entry from the installation.

Combining them into one entry did the trick.